Block income GRE ERSPAN traffic RHEL8
We have LinuxMachine(VoiceBiometrics) and customers VoiceBot.
LinuxMachine needs only SIP/SDP and RTP traffic from VoiceBot.
Customer network engineers configured on cisco device traffic mirroring(gre erspan) from VoiceBot to LinuxMachine.
But there are not only voice traffic is coming, but also everything else(all traffic from bot).
I tryed to accept only src/dst addresses on firewalld LinuxMachine, but its not working. Also I tryed to block GRE and block everything but this kind of traffic are imposible to block like that?! Maybe because of encapsulation?
How to block for example VRRP?

Sry for my English)

You cannot prevent traffic from arriving at your network interface. You can prevent the OS from handling the packets – that's what firewalld does – but the OS cannot refuse to receive them; everything that's sent towards your MAC will arrive at your network interface whether you want it or not, and therefore will be visible in Wireshark.
(Besides, how would the OS even know whether it should accept or reject a packet if it hasn't received that packet yet?)
The only way to reduce incoming traffic in this case is to filter it at the upstream switch (e.g. using switch hardware ACLs) – or to choose a better way of obtaining the data. I'm not sure exactly how your VoiceBiometrics system works, but it seems weird that it would need SPAN mirroring of all traffic.
Also: ERSPAN (and GRE in general) packets are IP-inside-IP, and although Wireshark shows you the innermost IP header, standard firewall rules only apply to the outermost one, i.e. 'src' is always the mirroring switch; the protocol is always GRE; and so on. More fine-grained filtering would require the firewall to specifically be configured to peek inside GRE payload.

thanks for answer.
Is it possible to forward filtered traffic from virtual machine interface ens192 to new virtual interface on linux, if I create it.  Idea: filter income mirrored traffic to ens192 and forward filtered traffic to new interface? so voicebiometrics will listen new interface

--mirrored-traffic-->ens192-->forward-only-sip-rtp-->ens0

In theory yes, using a Linux bridge + either nft or ebtables to filter the traffic being bridged, although I'm not sure how easy it will be to write an nftables rule that would match the inner IP header (inside the GRE tunnel). (Though at least it is possible with nftables; not sure if ebtables can do it at all.)

hi bro. dont know what to do, it is not working. could you see my new question https://stackoverflow.com/staging-ground/79158884
